Are there any REST APIs available to retrieve the properties of a deployed Azure OpenAI model?
Are there any REST APIs available that can be used to retrieve the properties of a deployed model or obtain a list of model deployments?
I have searched through the documentation but couldn't find any information specifically listing the properties of deployed models.
docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureopenai/models?view=rest-azureopenai-2024-05-01-preview



Are there any REST APIs available to retrieve the properties of a deployed Azure OpenAI model?

You can use the below REST API request to retrieve the properties of a deployed Azure OpenAI model.
In my environment, I had deployed model with the name gpt-35-turbo with properties like below:
Portal:

REST API:
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/{accountName}/deployments/{deploymentName}?api-version=2023-05-01 
Headers: 
Authorization: Bearer <access token>

Output:

Reference:
Deployments - Get - REST API (Azure Azure AI Services) | Microsoft Learn

Is there an alternative method to retrieve the list of deployments if the user does not know the subscription ID or resource group name? Let's assume the user has the endpoint and key linked to the account.

As of now, you can get the details from Management Api only.

As mentioned in the Azure Documentation
you can use the Deployment -GET API which will fetch the following

Model Name
Deployment Type
Model properties
Scale settings
provisioning state

Request HTTP
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/accountName/deployments/deploymentName?api-version=2023-05-01
Response
    {
  "id": "",
  "name": "deploymentName",
  "type": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/deployments",
  "properties": {
    "model": {
      "format": "OpenAI",
      "name": "ada",
      "version": "1"
    },
    "scaleSettings": {
      "scaleType": "Manual",
      "capacity": 1
    },
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
  }
}    

Link to Documentation: GET - Model Deployment
